# Multivariate Grouped Operation with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to make the switch from R's dplyr to pandas in Python. I've gone through several tutorials to learn the basics but I'm stuck on one task. I'd like to use the agg method in groupby to perform operations on more than one column. This is a trivial task in R as the example below illustrates:

```
library(dplyr)

DF <- data.frame('ID'=c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2),
                 'A'=c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                 'B'=c(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12))

IDgp <- group_by(DF, ID) %>%
  summarise(C = prod(B) / sum(A))


### # Output:
### 
### > DF
###   ID A  B
### 1  1 1  2
### 2  1 2  4
### 3  1 3  6
### 4  2 4  8
### 5  2 5 10
### 6  2 6 12
###
### > IDgp
### # A tibble: 2 x 2
###      ID     C
###   <dbl> <dbl>
### 1     1     8
### 2     2    64
```

In this example, I'm grouping on the ID column in DF and creating an arbitrary new variable based on both columns A and B. Is there a straightforward way to convert this example to Python using pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html):

```
df = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x: x['B'].prod() / x['A'].sum()).reset_index(name='C')
print (df)
   ID     C
0   1   8.0
1   2  64.0
```

Another solution with [`GroupBy.prod`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.prod.html) and [`GroupBy.sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html), divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html):

```
g = df.groupby('ID')
df = g['B'].prod().div(g['A'].sum()).reset_index(name='C')
print (df)
   ID     C
0   1   8.0
1   2  64.0
```

is same as:

```
df = df.groupby('ID')['B'].prod().div(df.groupby('ID')['A'].sum()).reset_index(name='C')
print (df)
   ID     C
0   1   8.0
1   2  64.0
```

Comment: This is great, thank you. The first approach is especially easy to comprehend. It looks like the apply method might be more flexible than the agg method.

Comment: Yes, exactly. `agg` working with each column (`Series`) separately, so not possible use in this solution.

Answer (score 1):

`apply` method as mentioned by jezrael is the way to go.

Alternatively, if you want to store intermediate results and assing new values by chaining, you could use `.agg` and `.assign`.

```
In [251]: df.groupby('ID').agg({'A': 'sum', 'B': 'prod'}).assign(C=lambda x: x.B/x.A)
Out[251]:
     A    B     C
ID
1    6   48   8.0
2   15  960  64.0
```

Comment: I guess I was hoping that .agg was more flexible. But I like this too. It's a clean approach.